# Throwing validation errors from Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

I am writing web api in C#, trying to follow REST concepts, i.e. success response will be HttpStatus: 200, validation errors will be 433 and so on.

I have ExceptionFilter registered for entire application in global.asax.

My question here is, for validation errors such as during authentication, if authentication failed, then how should the message be communicated back to client (it has to be a different status code such as 433 or 401).

As of now I am throwing custom exceptions from business layer. Is it recommended to throw exceptions in case of errors?

Following is the code sample:

Logger

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        if (context.Exception is ExceptionBase)
        {
            response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                new ErrorDTO() { ErrorCode = (int)((ExceptionBase)context.Exception).ExceptionCode, Messages = ((ExceptionBase)context.Exception).Message });
        }
        else {
            response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                new ErrorDTO() { ErrorCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Messages = "Error occured at server." });
        }
        context.Response = response;
        base.OnException(context);
        LogException(context);
    }

    private static void LogException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception != null)
        {
            Logger.Instance.LogError(context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, context.Exception);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.OnExceptionAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Business layer

```
public AuthorizationTokenDTO AuthenticateUser(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    User userEntity = _userRepository.GetUserWithAssociatedRole(userDTO.UserName);

    if (userEntity == null)
        throw new BLException("User does not exists.", ExceptionCode.RestApiValidation);

    ActiveDirectory activeDirectory = _activeDirectoryRepository.GetEntityById(ConfigurationSettings.GetConfigSetting<int>(ApplicationConstants.ActiveDirectoryId));

    if (activeDirectory == null)
        throw new BLException("UserName or password is incorrect.", ExceptionCode.RestApiValidation);

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        string password = EncryptionUtility.Decrypt(userDTO.Password, ConfigurationSettings.GetConfigSetting<string>(ApplicationConstants.PrivateKeyForRSAEncryption));

        if (!context.ValidateCredentials(userDTO.UserName, password))
            throw new BLException("UserName or password is incorrect.", ExceptionCode.RestApiValidation);

        UserAccessTokenDTO accessToken = GenrateNewUserAccessToken(userEntity);

        if (accessToken == null)
            throw new BLException("Error occured while generating access token.", ExceptionCode.RestApiValidation);

        return GetAuthorizationTokenDTO(userEntity, accessToken);
    }
}
```

Is it recommended to throw exceptions for such cases? or is there a better way to write Web APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The ExceptionFilter should only catch the "unhandled" exceptions, so to speak. You could either keep those exceptions in the BusinessLayer and catch them in the controller, or return some sort of object. Then just return those responses with the appropriate HttpStatusCode from the controler.

Alternatively you could wrap your response into something that also knows about HttpStatusCode (& error message).

Comment: Thank you for your response. these services will be consumed by WPF client. and if I use a request/response model to access rest api, then rest apis will always be returning httpstatuscode 200 and we will end-up having a lot of if/else conditions within the code (checking weather the response is success or failure). So how I am planning to do this is, capture these http exceptions in WPF and in WPF application class will capture these exceptions (http exceptions) and send a message to active view (via event aggregator) to let the view handle the exceptions from rest api

Comment: This way we are only writting code for success and failing where code has to fail, without impacting the real flow of code. i.e. error scenarios will be covered in error flow and real code is only worried about desired business.